# How to print multiple plots together in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, visualization

I am trying to print about 42 plots in 7 rows, 6 columns, but the printed output in jupyter notebook, shows all the plots one under the other. I want them in (7,6) format for comparison. I am using matplotlib.subplot2grid() function.

Note: I do not get any error, and my code works, however the plots are one under the other, vs being in a grid/ matrix form.
Here is my code:

```
def draw_umap(n_neighbors=15, min_dist=0.1, n_components=2, metric='euclidean', title=''):
fit = umap.UMAP(
    n_neighbors=n_neighbors,
    min_dist=min_dist,
    n_components=n_components,
    metric=metric
)
u = fit.fit_transform(df);
plots = []
plt.figure(0)
fig = plt.figure()
fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(10)
for i in range(7):
    for j in range(6):
        plt.subplot2grid((7,6), (i,j), rowspan=7, colspan=6)
        
    plt.scatter(u[:,0], u[:,1], c= df.iloc[:,0])
        
    plt.title(title, fontsize=8)

n=range(7)
d=range(6)

for n in n_neighbors:
    for d in dist:
        draw_umap(n_neighbors=n, min_dist=d, title="n_neighbors={}".format(n) + " min_dist={}".format(d))
```

I did refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37424530/how-to-make-more-than-10-subplots-in-a-figure) to get the plots in a grid and followed the code.
I also referred to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39659998/using-pyplot-to-create-grids-of-plots), and modified my code for size of the fig.

Is there a better way to do this using Seaborn?

What am I missing here? Please help!

Comment: Would you mind checking if the indent in the code you have given is correct? To me, it is not entirely clear where the `draw_umap` function ends and whether `plt.scatter` and `plt.title` should be in the `for j in range(6)` loop or not. Also, I notice that `n=range(7); d=range(6)` are superfluous as they are overwritten in the following loops.

Comment: The indent was right. I think, it is just an issue in jupyter notebook. I will double check the range values. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Both questions that you have linked contain solutions that seem more complicated than necessary. Note that `subplot2grid` is useful only if you want to create subplots of varying sizes which I understand is not your case. Also note that according to [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/demo_gridspec01.html) *Using GridSpec, as demonstrated in GridSpec demo is generally preferred*, and I would also recommend this function only if you want to create subplots of varying sizes.

The simple way to create a grid of equal-sized subplots is to use [`plt.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) which returns an array of `Axes` through which you can loop to plot your data as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65909342/14148248). That solution should work fine in your case seeing as you are plotting 42 plots in a grid of 7 by 6. But the problem is that in many cases you may find yourself not needing all the `Axes` of the grid, so you will end up with some empty frames in your figure.

Therefore, I suggest using a more general solution that works in any situation by first creating an empty figure and then adding each `Axes` with [`fig.add_subplot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_subplot) as shown in the following example:

```py
import numpy as np               # v 1.19.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # v 3.3.4

# Create sample dataset
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)  # random number generator
nvars = 8
nobs = 50
xs = rng.uniform(size=(nvars, nobs))
ys = rng.normal(size=(nvars, nobs))

# Create figure with appropriate space between subplots
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.3)

# Plot data by looping through arrays of variables and list of colors
colors = plt.get_cmap('tab10').colors
for idx, x, y, color in zip(range(len(xs)), xs, ys, colors):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 3, idx+1)
    ax.scatter(x, y, color=color)
```

[image: subplots_grid]

This could be done in seaborn as well, but I would need to see what your dataset looks like to provide a solution relevant to your case.

---

You can find a more elaborate example of this approach in the [second solution in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65459725/14148248).